# Filename not displaying in cmd

Tags: powershell

I have the following snippet

```
$svc_Files = gci | Where {$_.extension -eq ".svc"}
write-host "Building WSDL ..."
$cmd_svc = "`"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\x64\SvcUtil.exe`"" 
Foreach ($svc_File in $svc_Files) 
{
    write-host "& $cmd_svc http://id.web/Services/$svc_File?wsdl"
}
```

The problem is that the file name is not displaying. However, once i remove "?wsdl", the filename displays.

How can I get the file name to display with "?wsdl" on the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
write-host "& $cmd_svc http://id.web/Services/$svc_File`?wsdl"
```

You could also do this:

write-host "& $cmd_svc http://id.web/Services/$($svc_File)?wsdl"

Comment: Note to @Valamas: The backtick ` is the scape character of Powershell, like the backslash \ is the scape character of C#.

Comment: Underscores are fine in variable names...
$A_B = "Fred";
"$A_B`Hello"
returns
FredHello

Answer (score 3):

```
  write-host "& $cmd_svc http://id.web/Services/${svc_File}?wsdl"
```